# Combining When clauses gives me weird error in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, error-handling, rpc

Kotlin Code below works fine

```
 private inline fun <reified T> parseResponse(response: Any): Response<T> =
        when (response) {
            is T -> { Response(success = response, error = null) }
            is GetUserInfoResponseResult.Error -> {
                Response(
                    success = null,
                    error = Error(response.error.message ?: "", response.error.code?.name ?: "")
                )
            }
            is SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error -> {
                Response(
                    success = null,
                    error = Error(response.error.message ?: "", response.error.code?.name ?: "")
                )
            }
            else -> throw exception("Failed to process response ")
        }
```

However when I try to combine 2 when clauses

```
 private inline fun <reified T> parseResponse(response: Any): Response<T> =
        when (response) {
            is T -> { Response(success = response, error = null) }
            is GetUserInfoResponseResult.Error, SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error -> {
                Response(
                    success = null,
                    error = Error(response.error.message ?: "", response.error.code?.name ?: "")
                )
            }
         
            else -> throw exception("Failed to process response ")
        }
```

In intelliJ I got a red underline for `Error` in `SetuUserInfoResponseResult.Error`
saying

```
classifier Error does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized here
```

definitions

```
sealed class GetUserInfoResponseResult {

    data class Error(val error: GetUserInfoErrorResponse) : GetUserInfoResponseResult()

    data class Success(val success: GetUserInfoSuccessResponse) : GetUserInfoResponseResult()

}

sealed class SetUserInfoResponseResult {

    data class Error(val error: SetUserInfoErrorResponse) : SetUserInfoResponseResult()

    object Success : SetUserInfoResponseResult()

}
```

Comment: There should be an extra `is` before `SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error`. Adding that will give you more error messages though.

Comment: In order for me to be the most helpful, can you show how you have declared `GetUserInfoResponseResult.Error` and `SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error`?

Comment: I added one is, `is GetUserInfoResponseResult.Error, is SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error -> {.  }` and the red underline disappeared....

Comment: updated definition in description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `when` clause checks whether `response` is an instance of `GetUserInfoResponseResult.Error`, or `response` *is equal to* the companion object of `SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error`. The second half is an equality check, because you didn't write `is` before it. `SetUserInfoResponseResult.Error` does not have a companion object, hence the error.

Adding the `is` doesn't fix everything. There are still errors where you try to access `response.error.message`. This is because smart casts only works when you are checking for a single type. Since you are checking for 2, the compile-time type of `response` is not smart casted, and is still `Any`.

You can fix this by introducing a common interface that both error types implements:

```
interface UserInfoErrorResponseResult {
    val error: UserInfoErrorResponse
}

interface UserInfoErrorResponse {
    val message: String?
    val code: ErrorCode? // I assume you have an ErrorCode class like this
}
```

Then you can just check for one type - `is UserInfoErrorResponseResult` - and smart cast would work:

```
 private inline fun <reified T> parseResponse(response: Any): Response<T> =
        when (response) {
            is T -> { Response(success = response, error = null) }
            is UserInfoErrorResponseResult -> {
                Response(
                    success = null,
                    error = Error(response.error.message ?: "", response.error.code?.name ?: "")
                )
            }
         
            else -> throw exception("Failed to process response ")
        }
```

Here's an example of how your classes would look like, implementing those interfaces, with some assumptions of how `GetUserInfoErrorResponse` and `SetUserInfoErrorResponse` look like.

```
data class GetUserInfoErrorResponse(
    override val message: String?,
    override val code: ErrorCode?
): UserInfoErrorResponse

data class SetUserInfoErrorResponse(
    override val message: String?,
    override val code: ErrorCode?
): UserInfoErrorResponse

sealed class GetUserInfoResponseResult {

    data class Error(override val error: GetUserInfoErrorResponse) :
        GetUserInfoResponseResult(), UserInfoErrorResponseResult

    data class Success(val success: GetUserInfoSuccessResponse) : GetUserInfoResponseResult()

}

sealed class SetUserInfoResponseResult {

    data class Error(override val error: SetUserInfoErrorResponse) :
        SetUserInfoResponseResult(), UserInfoErrorResponseResult

    object Success : SetUserInfoResponseResult()

}
```

Basically, you should just add `override` to everything the interface needs, and it should work.